# AWS Lambda using promise.all works in local environment, callback returns null when deployed

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, promise

Here is the lambda code. The point here is to get a bunch of information from API calls and send to snowflake via `FiveTran`. None of that seems all that relevant, I'm just trying to understand why `promise.all()` is working in the local environment and failing in deployment.

```
'use strict'

import { 
    Callback,
    Context,
    Handler,
} from "aws-lambda"

import { ServiceException } from '@destpet/dp-validation'
import { Logger } from '@destpet/dp-logger'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
const trace = Logger('trace')
const debug = Logger('debug')
const warn = Logger('warn')
const error = Logger('error')
import data from "./data"
import { createBuilderStatusReporter, forEachTrailingCommentRange, getDefaultLibFilePath } from "typescript"

const ENV:string = process.env['NODE_ENV']
const lambda:string = 'dp_PredictHQ_etl_v1' 
const version:string = '1.0.0'

const CORS_ALL_ORIGINS = {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}



export interface FiveTranRequest {
    agent: string;
    state: {transactionsCursor: string};
    secrets: {apiToken: string};
}

export interface FiveTranResponse {
    state: {transactionsCursor: string};
    insert: {transactions:Array<object>};
    delete?: {transactions:Array<object>};
    schema?: {transactions: {primary_key: Array<string>}};
    hasMore: boolean;
    test: any;
}

export interface FiveTranError {
    errorMessage: string;
    errorType: string;
    stackTrace?: Array<Array<string>>;
}

export interface LocationInfo {
    Location_ID: string;
    Latitude: string;
    Longitude: string;
}

export interface AllAPICallsReturn {
    responsePromiseArray: any,
    locations: Array<number>
}

const lib = {

    /**
     * Process service request
     */
     processRequest: async (
            event: FiveTranRequest,
            resp: FiveTranResponse, 
            callback:Callback
        ): Promise<void> => {

        try {
            trace('just inside of processrequest',`${lambda}: processRequest`, null, resp)
            const endDate = new Date
            endDate.setDate(endDate.getUTCDate() + 90)
            const dateArray = lib.createDateRange(endDate)
            
            const locationArray = data;
            
            let transactionsArray = []
            
            let locationArrayPointer = 0
            let pointerIncrement = 10
            
            while (locationArrayPointer <= locationArray.length) {
                let templocationArray = locationArray.slice(locationArrayPointer,locationArrayPointer + pointerIncrement)
                let apiDataFetch = await lib.allAPICalls(dateArray, templocationArray)
                let apiDataParse = lib.parseAllData(apiDataFetch.fetchPromiseArray, apiDataFetch.locations)
                transactionsArray = transactionsArray.concat(apiDataParse)
                locationArrayPointer += pointerIncrement;
            }
            
            resp['state']['transactionsCursor'] = '2021-10-04'
            resp['schema']['transactions'] = {primary_key: ['id']}
            resp['hasMore'] = false
            resp['insert']['transactions'] = transactionsArray
            resp['test'] = transactionsArray
            
            
            // trace('right before callback',`${lambda}: processRequest`, null, resp)
            callback(null, resp)

        } catch (e:any) {
            error('Unable to process request', `${lambda}:processRequest`, null, e)
            console.log(e)

            let stackTrace = (e instanceof Error && e.stack) ? [e.stack.split('\n')] : [['No stack trace']]

            const errResponse: FiveTranError = {
                errorMessage: (e instanceof ServiceException) ? e.message : e.toString(),
                errorType: 'DP_FiveTran_API_Lambda_Error',
                stackTrace
            }

            const errorCode = (e instanceof ServiceException) ? e.errorCode : 500

            callback(null, resp)
        }
    },

    createDateRange : ( endDate : Date) :Array<string> => {
       let dateArray = [];

       let datePointer = new Date()
       datePointer.setUTCFullYear(2017)
       datePointer.setUTCMonth(7)
       datePointer.setUTCDate(1)

       while(endDate > datePointer) {
           let internalArray = []
           let startInterval = new Date(datePointer.getUTCFullYear(), datePointer.getUTCMonth(), 1)
           let endInterval = new Date(datePointer.getUTCFullYear(), datePointer.getUTCMonth() + 2, 0)
           internalArray.push(startInterval.toISOString().split('T')[0])
           internalArray.push(endInterval.toISOString().split('T')[0])
           dateArray.push(internalArray)
           datePointer = new Date(datePointer.getUTCFullYear(), datePointer.getUTCMonth() + 2, 1)
       }

       dateArray[dateArray.length - 1][1] = endDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]

       return dateArray
    },

    APICall : async (date: string, location: LocationInfo) => {
        
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const dateS = date[0]
            const dateE = date[1]
            const data = {
                "active": {
                    "gte": dateS,
                    "lte": dateE
                },
                'phq_rank_school_holidays': true,
                'phq_rank_public_holidays': true,
                'phq_rank_observances': true,
                'phq_rank_academic_holiday': true,
                'phq_attendance_academic_social': true,
    
                'location': {
                    'geo': {
                        'lat': Number(location.Latitude),
                        'lon': Number(location.Longitude),
                        'radius': '12km'
                    }        
                },
                "phq_attendance_sports": {
                    "stats": [
                        "sum"
                    ]
                }
            }
    
            const requestBody = {
                headers: {
                "Authorization": "redacted",
                "Accept": "application/json"
                },
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
                'Content-type': 'application/json' 
            }

            fetch('https://api.predicthq.com/v1/features', requestBody)
                .then(r => {
                    return r.json();
                })
                .then(response => {
                    resolve(response);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    reject(new ServiceException('APICall promise rejected', 500))
                    error('in APICall','',null,error)
                })
        })
    },
    
    allAPICalls : async (dateArray : Array<string>, locationsArray : Array<LocationInfo>): Promise<any> => {
        const promiseArray: Array<Promise<any>> = [];
        const locations: Array<number> = [];
        
        locationsArray.forEach( location => {
            dateArray.forEach( date => {
                promiseArray.push(lib.APICall(date, location))
                locations.push(Number(location.Location_ID))
            })
        })
        
        let fetchPromiseArray, responsePromiseArray
        try {
            fetchPromiseArray = await Promise.all(promiseArray).catch(e => {error('','',null,e)})
        } catch (err) {
            error('error in all api calls',`${lambda}: processRequest`, null, err)
            console.log(err)
        }
        return {
            fetchPromiseArray,
            locations
        }
    },

    dataParse : (dataObject) => {
        const parsedData = {};
        const recursiveParse = ( recursiveObject = dataObject, fieldTitle = '' ) => {
           for (const property in recursiveObject) {
                if (property !== 'phq_attendance_academic_social') {
                    let dataFieldTitle
                    if (fieldTitle === '') {
                        dataFieldTitle = property
                    } else {
                        dataFieldTitle = fieldTitle + '_' + property
                    }
                    if (typeof recursiveObject[property] !== 'object') {
                        parsedData[dataFieldTitle] = recursiveObject[property]
                    } else {
                        recursiveParse(recursiveObject[property], dataFieldTitle)
                    }
               }
           } 
        }
        recursiveParse();
        return parsedData
    },

    parseAllData : ( dataArray, locationsArray) => {
        const transactionsArray = [];
        let id = 0;
        dataArray.forEach( (resultArray, index) => {
            resultArray.results.forEach( individualResult => {
                let transaction = lib.dataParse(individualResult)
                transaction['Location'] = locationsArray[index]
                transaction['id'] = id;
                transactionsArray.push(transaction)
                id += 1;
            })
        })
        return transactionsArray;
    }
}

/**
 * Lambda service handler
 * 
 * @param event 
 * @param context 
 * @param callback 
 */
 export const handler: Handler<any, void> = async (
        event: FiveTranRequest,
        context: Context, 
        callback: Callback
    ): Promise<void> => {

    let resp: FiveTranResponse = {
        state: {transactionsCursor: null},
        schema: {transactions: null},
        insert: {transactions: null},
        hasMore: false,
        test: ''
    }

    if (event['detail-type'] === 'warm') {
        trace('...Warm...')
        callback(null, null)
    } else {
        debug(`Executing service handler`, `${lambda}:handler`)
        lib.processRequest(event, resp, callback).catch(err => {console.log(`Error: ${err}`)})
    }
}
```

When run in the local environment this works exactly as I want it to, in deployment it returns null. Using *cloudwatch* logs I've determined that it runs until the `promise.all()` in the `lib.allAPICalls` function and then just... exits or stops or something. I have the timeout set to 60 seconds and this returns null in about 6. Honestly baffled here, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: figured it out. Solution is one single word. Added "await" for the `lib.processRequest` call at the very end.

Comment: So it looks like you're collecting a series of API calls, executing them concurrently and then waiting for the result in the Promise.all. My guess is that your lambda has no access to the API or doesn't have the resources to execute all these requests in time. Have you tried upping the RAM on the AWS Lambda? This will push the lambda to higher execution tier with better IO performance.

Comment: Mixing `.then()` and `async await` syntaxes makes for very confusing code, with particular regard to error handling.